# Serving pdf links with Gunicorn when django DEBUG True and False

Tags: django, gunicorn

Any ideas what can go wrong that would cause a Gunicorn not be able to serve a link to a pdf file when DEBUG in django settings.py is turned to False? The site still works great but pdf links are not served.

When DEBUG=True the site with links to pdf files works great and gunicorn serves pdf links and pdf shows on screen, whereas when DEBUG=False and ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my provider's IP'] (all other configurations in settings.py are the same) and gunicorn.conf is untouched in both situations, pdf links fail.

Comment: Is it static? Or not?

Comment: Well, the pdf link is created by a user upload. In this sense it is not static.

Comment: ok, i assume that it is a media file then. what are your media-settings?

Comment: /site_media/static is doing great and all .js etc load and appear on screen when selected by the browser debugger

Comment: but your media files are not the same as static: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016589/what-is-the-difference-between-static-files-and-media-files-in-django

Comment: You are correct. It had to do with user privileges on the media files folder. Btw do you know of any good strategy to backup media files (that users upload etc?). Thank you very much. I gave you a thumbs up!

Comment: I have used this library several years ago: https://github.com/django-dbbackup/django-dbbackup