# Django cannot find "/media/image.png" when placed in root folder

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have the following structure

```
my app/
|_my_app/
|  |_templates/
|_static/
|_media/
|_utils/
|_main.py
|_manage.py
|_.gitignore
```

and having the in `template.html`

`<img src="./media/image.png">`
then it casts a GET 404 error `Cannot find /media/image.png`.

I have also tried relative path (relative to the template i.e `<img src="../../media/image.png">`.

Moving the media folder into static (and including `{% load static %}` I can do

`<img src="{% static '/media/image.png'">`

without any issues.

1. Why can't it find `./media/image.png` in the first part?
2. Is there a way to do the "static" trick but with another tag (say `media`) e.g `<img src="{% media 'image.png' ">` to avoid absolute paths?

Comment: You have to add MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in settings and in urls.py.

Comment: The fact that you need to write the url manually means this is not a users media. Meaning this is a **static** image. Just put it in your static folder then.

Comment: Biplove, I have added those, and it wont work

Comment: are you trying to show uploaded content or static content?

Comment: @CutePoison check this question [What is the difference between static files and media files in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016589/what-is-the-difference-between-static-files-and-media-files-in-django)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django html template can't find static css and js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437690/django-html-template-cant-find-static-css-and-js-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new folder named **img** in the static folder, then paste your image in the **img** folder such that the path to the image will be like this: **static -> img -> image.png**. You can load the image in HTML like this:

```
<img src="{% static 'img/image.png'">
```

Comment: That is exactly the workaround I'm doing at the moment - the question is, why I just cant place a folder called `media` in root and then use `scr="media/img.png"`